# where generic тип поддерживает операцию сложения

Tags: kotlin, generics

Допустим я хочу реализовать операцию сложения для произвольных аргументов:

```kotlin
fun <A, B, RES> sum(a: A, b: B): RES = a + b
```

Разумеется оператор `A.plus(B)` не реализован.

Хорошо, тогда создадим интерфейс:

```kotlin
interface SummableWith<IN, OUT>{
    operator fun plus(other: IN): OUT;
}
fun <A, B, RES> sum(a: A, b: B): RES where A : SummableWith<B, RES> = a + b
```

Но вот незадача: теперь тип `A` обязательно должен наследовать мой интерфейс, а добавлять интерфейсы с уже созданным типам я не могу (например к `Int`).

Как я могу указать, что переменные типов `A` и `B` имеют поддержку операции `A.plus(B)`?

При этом мне **необходимо** знать тип `RES`, поэтому проверкой типов в рантайме обойти не получится